# How to set absolute position on JPanel which in BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, css-position, layout-manager

I have a main panel that looks like this:

```
JPnael mainPanel = new JPanel();
mainPanel .setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

And I include sub panels, like this:

```
mainPanel.add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH));
mainPanel.add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER));
```

I want to create another JPanel, but not in BorderLayout, it needs to be absolute position. How can I do this?

Update:
I tried this variant, but it not suitable for BorderLayout

```
JPanel absPanel = new JPanel();
JLabel absLbl = new JLabel("aaaaaaaaa");
absPanel.setLayout(null);
absPanel.add(absLbl);
absPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
mainPanel.add(absPanel, ???);
```

Comment: *"I want to create another JPanel, but not in BorderLayout, its need be absolute position"*  No it doesn't.  Provide ASCII art of how the GUI is suppose to look at normal size, and when expanded.

Comment: I would avoid null/absolute layouts with a passion, instead, if I found that I need to position the componets with more accuracy then is provided by the available, I'd look to developing my own. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635952/java-layout-proportions-creating-a-scalable-square-panel/14636828#14636828) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819669/absolute-positioning-graphic-jpanel-inside-jframe-blocked-by-blank-sections/11822601#11822601) for example

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what is the visual effect you're trying to achieve, but you may try using the [layered pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)