# Drawing resizable square chessboard in JFrame hierarchy

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to draw a chessboard with `setColor(c)` and `fillRect(x, y, dx, dy)` methods of `Graphics`. I want it to be resizable according to the modifications of the window, but keeping the shape of a square. Additionally, I want it to be placed in the middle of the encompassing panel.

As it may be seen below, the last one is not the case. Apart from that everything resizes well.

[image: what I got]

1. `JFrame` is split into two JPanels using `GridBagLayout` keeping the proportion 3:1. The upper cell uses `fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH`. The corresponding `upperPanel` is thus stretched as red border shows.
2. Then this `upperPanel` contains another `JPanel boardPanel` used solely for the chessboard itself. This part is definitely wrong here but I don't know how to fix it.

a. `upperPanel` defines the following layout in its constructor:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
add(boardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I wanted to stretch the frame as far as possible within the grid cell.

b. `boardPanel` has then such layout:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
```

Frankly speaking nothing else worked. The panel contains only graphics being drawn in `paintComponent(Graphics g)`.

3. `setColor(c)` and `fillRect(x, y, dx, dy)` is done in a loop within `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of `boardPanel`, starting from `x=0, y=0`. The length of a chessboard cell edge is determined every time this method is called through calculations on `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` of an `upperPanel` (as `boardPanel` is a nested class in `upperPanel`).

Is there a way to make `boardPanel` adjust to what was drawn within it? So that the `boardPanel` is the size of an actual image of the board. I guess then layout of `upperPanel` would place it in the center of itself.

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635952/java-layout-proportions-creating-a-scalable-square-panel/14636828#14636828)?

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, because attn screenshort talking about another issue

Comment: @MadProgrammer precisely, however I wondered (1) if it can be achieved a bit easier (for example withot custom layout) (2) if chessboard can be plainly painted instead of being constructed from buttons. Your solution is superb there but I was wondering if it's the only one or you just prepared an elastic one with greater functionality.

Comment: See also [Making a robust, resizable Swing Chess GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/418556).

Comment: @mKorbel you mean that pure code would be better than description? The question seemed to me quite abstract.

Comment: @infoholic_anonymous question seemed to me quite abstract. == agree after link to code is posted by Andrew Thompson, otherwise isn't

Comment: Well, the layout is quite flexible, and having each cell as a component provides quite a bit of additional functionality (set the icon or add components to it), however, you could paint the cells manually through custom painting, but that would introduce quite a bit of work, not just through the painting, but the overall management of the game

Comment: @MadProgrammer but is there a way within the line of thinking I posted to make it work? To force the JPanel `a` containing the chessboard drawing to fit that chessboard and then to place it in the center of a JPanel `b`, where `b` contains [only] such containter?

Comment: *"To force the JPanel a containing the chessboard drawing to fit that chessboard and then to place it in the center of a JPanel b, where b contains [only] such containter?"*  Given the linked source code (in my comment) does just that (while expanding the board to the largest square size available), I'm guessing you've not even glanced at the thread yet.  :-/

Comment: If, you are manually painting the cheeseboard, then you should be able to calculate the x/y offsets that will center the border.  Dropping the board inside multiple containers isn't really going to achieve anything, because the outer portions (width/height) of the component will still be larger than the size of the board itself...

Comment: @AndrewThompson your solution is great. I was just more interested in fixing my solution than finding new one. Excuse me for making my question so imprecise. I think I'd better delete this one and make another more detailed. Thanks for your time.

Comment: *"I think I'd better delete this one and make another more detailed."* Please [edit this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26882972/edit) rather than ask a new one!